# Cross origin file download in Django

Tags: django

I wrote a small website using django. The website is hosted on pythonanywhere while the media files are aws s3. How can I create a link to download these files since they're not from the same origin. Below is what I've been able to put together but it only refreshes the page.

```
def download(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Music, slug=slug)
    print(obj.audio_file.path)
    file_name = obj.title
    file_path = obj.audio_file.path
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f1:
        response = HttpResponse(f1.read(), content_type='audio/mpeg')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % file_name
        return response
```

My urls.py

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.download, name='download'),
```

And here is my html

```
<a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="{% url 'music:download' song.slug %}">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Comment: Hi, you have to be sure that ```object.title``` does not have slash, it's not permitted in file name.

Comment: It doesn't have any slash

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a button on your site that downloads a file from S3, you just need to change the `href` attribute on that button to the S3 one:

```
<a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="s3 url goes here">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

...replacing `s3 url goes here` appropriately. If the S3 URL is made up of two parts, say `http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com/` and then the `slug` field of the `song` variable that you're injecting into the template, then you can just concatenate them in the template:

```
<a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com/{{ song.slug }}">DOWNLOAD</a>
```